# Groupby, lag and sum in python: Memory and Time Efficient way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector

I have a 15 million row dataset with 30 columns.
One column is ID, another is YearMonth, and the remaining 28 columns are a mix of int and float variables.
I'm only showing 5 columns for illustration purposes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.repeat(range(1,150001),100),'YearMonth':[i for i in range(1,101)]*150000,
                  'Var1':np.random.randint(0,5,15000000),'Var2':np.random.randint(0,5,15000000),
                  'Var3':np.random.randint(0,5,15000000)})
```

Assume that the data is first sorted on ID and YearMonth level.
Now, For each column (Var1, Var2, Var3 - in this case), I want to groupby on ID column and take sum of multiple lag values. Because the nested for loops were inefficient, I attempted to write the following code using numpy and vectors:

```
df = df.assign(**{'{}_total_lag_in_prev_{}_{}'.format(col,int(k[0]),int(k[1])): 
                  np.concatenate([
                      df.groupby(['ID'])[col].shift(i).fillna(0).to_numpy().reshape(-1,1) 
                      for i in range(int(k[0]),int(k[1])+1)
                  ],axis=1).sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1) 
                  for col in ['Var1','Var2','Var3']
                 for k in [(1,2),(3,4)]})
```

This works perfectly. But what if I want to improve and optimise the code?
How can I decrease the execution time and improve the memory utilisation?

Comment: Anyone knows it?

Comment: Hi, perhaps you'll get some new ideas here: https://pythonspeed.com/performance/

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful. Could you still give it a try to modify the code that runs faster?

Comment: If you want more attention, a bounty is a tool for exactly that...